# Google App Engine & Amazon Cloud,which is better?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, platform

I'm going to deploy my application on one of them,
and have no idea which is better.

Comment: Better for what exactly. What kind of application have you built? What language did you use? What are your requirements?

Comment: Google will give you lots of articles comparing both of them.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude shore, but you have 150+ questions vs 1 answer ...

Comment: I don't see how it's "subjective and argumentative", as the would-be closers say, that Amazon's offer is far more flexible, Google's easier to use (and free for small loads) but with lots of limitations!

Comment: @Alex, the question doesn't specify any kind of scope. It is like saying "What is better, burger king or McDougles? -- Depends what you want.

Comment: @Aiden, the question is more like "what is better exercise, swimming or weight-lifting" -- there are objective points, not just subjective ones of taste!

Of course "what's better" depends on what you want, but the Q can be answered by pointing out the main objective differences between the forms of exercise you get with each practice. Just saying "it depends" without at all mentioning the main differences between them is, IMHO, less helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's Cloud services, at this time, are much more general and flexible, while Google App Engine essentially fits some specific classes of applications that can live within its specific limitations (those limitations are being gradually relaxed, as GAE adds features and allows you to pay to exceed certain quotas, but that does not mean GAE will become a completely general-purpose platform the way Amazon's services are).

If your app can live within GAE's limitations, then GAE presents advantages: free up to a certain quota, almost no system configuration / administration overhead, etc. But if you need total flexibility -- for example, if you want to code part of your apps in C or C++, and that's just one of many examples -- then GAE is not suitable, while Amazon (for a price, in both money and sysadm overhead) can accomodate you.

Comment: But I don't see why Amazon EC2 is related with "cloud",it seems just like ordinary vps..

Comment: You can provision as many instances as you want, *dynamically* -- big ones, medium ones, in-between -- rapidly start them up, rapidly tear them down, keep them as long as you want (and are willing to pay for;-) -- what "ordinary vps" do you know, that lets you do THAT kind of little trick, hm?-)

Comment: Is there any data support for this?Sometimes 1000 remarks can't compete for 1 data.

Comment: There's a teraword of information and documentation about each service, and it's easy (and, for app engine, free) to sign up and try both yourself. You can just as easily read all sort of analysis by the usual industry analysts, e.g. at http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/11/Comparing-EC2-App-Engine-Azure. What "data support" are you looking for? And, I'm STILL waiting to hear about the "ordinary vps" you think are just like EC2 (dynamic provisioning and everything) -- cat got your tongue?-)

Comment: Thank you Alex.I've learned much following your link.BTW,is there a cloud-computing market sharing chart available?

Comment: @Shore, I've never seen such a chart, I'd be really curious, especially once MS gets seriously going with Azure and IBM's enterprise oriented offerings also get traction -- I know Rackspace is in the market for general-purpose offers, and companies such as Intuit (known for Quicken, QuickBooks &c) and salesforce (think CRM) are selling specialized cloud computing, too, but I have no idea about market share. I spent 4+ years of my life _building_ a cloud (at Google, uber tech lead for cluster management) and I'm now in Business Intelligence, so I'd _really_ love to know!-)

Comment: hope this link helps,but I'm not so trusting it though:http://www.istrategylabs.com/buzz-monitoring-google-vs-microsoft-sentiment-analysis/

Comment: @Shore, thanks, interesting brand-comparison approach -- not that it can say much about market share (plus, Amazon's been selling ec2 for a while - s3 is just a storage solution, so they're comparing apples to oranges;-).

Answer (score 0):

If you've already written your app, and just want to deploy it, I'd have to say AWS is your best bet. AWS is a platform (or rather, EC2 is), and deploying an existing app is easy. App Engine, on the other hand, provides an entire development environment, at a much higher level of abstraction, which has significant advantages when it comes to scaling, but requires you to have written your app to work on it.

Comment: I don't see why Amazon EC2 is related with "cloud",it seems just like ordinary vps.What do you think?

Comment: An individual EC2 instance is more or less the same, yes. The 'cloud' is a factor because you can provision and turn up and down as many instances as you want with very short notice.

Answer (score 0):

Now how about Free Amazon EC2 for a year to do a better comparision. Check this out.

http://www.buzzingup.com/2010/10/amazon-announces-free-cloud-services-for-new-developers/

Answer (score 0):

No one is king in this field because both amazon and google have their own pros and cons. for the finally decision you have to study deep about both or you have to analyze what you required for you apps.
no doubt aws is old in this field and they have lot of good quality stuff but remember google is fast growing in cloud computing.

personally aws is easy to use and training and support is easily available on the other side google is his early stage and bit complex interface for newbie

so you can learn from you requirement